# Merge And overwrite common columns in two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe  **A** with **80** columns, and I did group by **A** and **Sum 20** columns

E.g.

```
New_df=A.groupby(['X','Y','Z'])['a','b','c',......].sum().reset_Index()--------(1)
```

Then I want to overwrite the values in columns which are present in **A** with the **New_df** columns value which are common.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
cols1=set(A.columns.tolist())
cols2=set(New_df.columns.tolist())
common_cols = list(cols1.intersection(cols2))
A[common_cols]=New_df[common_cols]
```

to find the columns that the two df's have in common , then replace those in the first with the columns from the second.
This will give you results for example given an initial A:

```
   x  y     
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  3  c
```

and New_df:

```
   z  y
0  4  d
1  5  e
2  6  f
```

And we wind up with  final 'A', with y column taken from New_df:

```
   x  y
0  1  d
1  2  e
2  3  f
```

Comment: sorry but this creates Dataframe with common columns but I want to overwrite the common columns present in A with columns with groupby New_df columns values.

Comment: this replaces the columns in A that occur in New_df, with the values in New_df. Did you try it?

Comment: When I test , I get A with new column taken from new_df as desired. Maybe show the code you use to run this? See example above.